# Удаление строк из датафрейма с булевой маской

Tags: python, pandas

Необходимо удалить строки в которых значения столбца 'b' меньше нуля

```
num = [[1, 3, 6],
   [5, -6, 18],
   [0, -1, 16],
   [4, 56, 18]]
df = pd.DataFrame(num, columns=['a','b','c'])
df.drop(df[df['b']<0], Axis=0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Если "удалять" выбирая, то df = df[df['b'] >= 0]

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

num = [[1, 3, 6],
   [5, -6, 18],
   [0, -1, 16],
   [4, 56, 18]]
df = pd.DataFrame(num, columns=['a','b','c'])
df = df.loc[df['b'] >= 0.0]

print(df)
```

Проверяем на условие df['b'] >= 0.0, тогда копируем. Естественно минусовые не попадут.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите именно через `drop`, то можно так:

```py
df.drop(index=df[df['b']<0].index, inplace=True)
```

Саму маску в `drop` передать нельзя, но можно сделать удаление по индексу. И старайтесь не использовать устаревший параметр `axis`, давно есть возможность использовать более понятные варианты параметров `index=`, `columns=`.

А так то при операциях по маске лучше использовать `df.loc`, но нужно инвертировать условие, что можно сделать использовав отрицание через `~`, если не хотите думать над логикой условия, чтобы его поменять:

```py
df = df.loc[~df['b']<0]
```